# .gcda files not getting generated in C

Tags: c

Can you please let me know that which flag you have build now . That you were able to generate the .gcda files now. I am using this flag for compilation .

```
CFLAGS_linux= -m32 -fPIC -g -pg -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage --coverage
```

and for linking I am using this

```
LDFLAGS_linux= -m elf_i386 -Bstatic -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.1/32 --whole-archive -lgcov --no-whole-archive -Bdynamic -shared -L/usr/lib -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage -lc
```

I am able to generate .gcno and my process is also coming up. But when I am trying to run the process and performing some operation the .gcda is not getting generated.

Comment: You would have to add more information. How do you run tests? Where? Where are your sources and binary file when you are running tests. gcov is sensitive in these areas.

Comment: the `.gcda` file is not generated unless `__gcov_flush` gets called (it's an exit hook by default). If you're not terminating the app, then you need to **manually** invoke `__gcov_flush` at some point in the execution.

Comment: It has worked for me now. The issue because of different version of compiler it was not working after adding this flag for linking it worked now. LD=GCC.